# Accessing vs 2008 project running on localhost from a vm

Tags: visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer-6, vmware

I have a VM running IE6 and a VS 2008 project. I want to be able to access it via VM. So when I hit F5 a virtual server (or something) is running om my machine and i can test it by going to http://localhost:{some port}/

i wanted to access from the VM but i've tried http://{pc-name}:{same-port}/ and http://{pc-ip}:{same-port}/ but had no success.

I don't want to use IIS because I don't want to publish every time I'm testing it on IE6. I just want to test on IE6 on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You must use IIS and you shouldn't publish you application every time you change something. You will just use link, like you were trying to use before: http://{pc-name}/{virtual folder name}. I think you are missing something, cos VS virtual server is used only for local debugging and IIS can completely replace it.